# A list of worldbuilding resources

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources, software-recommendations

We are occasionally asked for advice about the worldbuilding process.  By its creative and imaginative nature, the process of worldbuilding doesn't have a single obvious starting point or a step-by-step process that is universally applicable to all worldbuilding efforts.

The answer below lists many worldbuilding resources that can help you with your, "where do I go next?" questions.  We recommend that you review these resources before asking us, so that if you do need to ask, you know *exactly* what problem you need to solve.

Please note that there are many specific questions assigned the [worldbuilding-process](/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process) and [worldbuilding-resources](/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-resources) tags.  Most of them are too specific to be generally useful for the purpose of this post.  We recommend reviewing them both for their content and to get an idea of the kinds of specific resource and process questions we answer here.

The answer has been created as a community wiki, which means everyone is invited to add resources.  I and the moderators reserve the right to remove entries that we deem trivial or inappropriate.  Everyone is welcome to help with formatting to keep the list neat and organized.

1. If you have questions, please post them as a comment to this question.  When addressed, please delete the comment.
2. Please *DO NOT* post additional answers to this question.  Answers other than the community wiki will be arbitrarily deleted.
3. If your entry can reasonably be listed under an existing header, please do so.  Create new headers only when absolutely necessary.
4. Your entry must link to the resource (no non-link entries).

> **Clarification:** Due to James' query about whether or not it makes sense for this question to exist here on Main, I opened a [Meta discussion asking why it shouldn't exist on Main](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/40609).  The post on Meta is NOT identical to this post.  My personal belief is that this question belongs on Main.

Comment: I don't oppose this effort but it doesn't really fit here.  You could certainly include a list of resources/processes in the tag wikis.  That being said I am willing to discuss whether this makes sense to keep on the site and open, but its probably worth a meta discussion.  The resources/processes tags require specific needs and the answer a specific tool.

Comment: Thanks, I don't mean to shoot the idea down...well I mean I do, but I also like the idea.  Figure we can sort out whether an exception to the rule makes sense in this case.

Comment: I appreciate you forcing the issue! The question has come up before (which I think I answered).  Where's the Wiki and how do we edit it?

Comment: Well no matter where you put it, please don't get rid of it completely. It's very useful, and I'm sure will cut down on lots of basic level and redundant questions. Mine included!

Comment: This list is in dire need of alt-history-specific resources. Re: [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207996/are-there-any-tools-that-people-use-to-generate-borders-during-alternate-histori), tools/etc for partially altering Earth's borders.

Comment: @rek I don't know what "dire need" is, but I've added the link from Key_Abrade's post. Please note that the answer is a community wiki. You can edit in info yourself.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**Worldbuilding Lexicon**

- [What is a LitRPG?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9877/37029)

**A Word about Copyright**

- [How does using Worldbuilding.SE affect my copyright?](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/77923/12916)
- [When is a person a co-author of a joint work?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/78024/12916)

**General Guides**

- [Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory): [Some theoretical considerations to world building methods](https://medium.com/universe-factory/some-theoretical-considerations-to-world-building-methods-7bfafe2870b)
- A short guide to worldbuilding - [Part 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/comments/6k4bjc/a_short_guide_to_worldbuilding_part_1/), [Part 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/comments/6k9qzc/a_short_guide_to_worldbuilding_part_2/), [Part 3](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/comments/6koud8/a_short_guide_to_worldbuilding_part_3_final/)
- Roll for Fantasy worldbuilding guide - [Part 1](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/world-building.php), [Part 2](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/world-building-part-two.php), [Part 3](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/world-building-part-three.php)
- [Ultimate worldbuilding guide for writers](https://hilbertthm90.wordpress.com/2019/01/18/how-start-worldbuilding-writers/)
- [Guide To World-Building: How To Write Fantasy, Sci-Fi And Real-Life Worlds](https://writersedit.com/fiction-writing/the-ultimate-guide-to-world-building-how-to-write-fantasy-sci-fi-and-real-life-worlds/)
- [Short Primer of the Making of Invented Cultures](https://cbbforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=5618&p=233357&hilit=primer#p233357)
- [The Great Ethnographical Questionnaire](https://web.archive.org/web/20240119224714/https://bethisad.com/questionnaire.htm)
- [Workshop on Villain Creation](http://www.giantitp.com/articles/rTKEivnsYuZrh94H1Sn.html)
- [Lymyaael's Literary Rants](https://curiosityquills.com/limyaael/)
- [30 Days of Worldbuilding](http://www.web-writer.net/fantasy/days/)
- [Orion's Arm Resources](https://www.orionsarm.com/xcms.php?r=oa-page&page=gen_worldbuilding_links)

**The First Step**

- [Is there a "best" way to start worldbuilding?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42696/is-there-a-best-way-to-start-worldbuilding)
- [The Rules of Quick and Dirty Worldbuilding](https://io9.gizmodo.com/the-rules-of-quick-and-dirty-worldbuilding-5039477)
- [Worldbuilding Pillars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/112851/in-order-to-build-a-fantasy-world-what-basic-pillars-are-needed/112859#112859)
- [How can I break down the task of creating a world into manageable chunks?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2/40609)
- [Worldbuilding Questionnaire #1](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxfxDe6Ap7_mMGxhNVhTSHBLZWM/edit?pli=1)
- [Worldbuilding Questionnaire #2](https://www.sfwa.org/2009/08/04/fantasy-worldbuilding-questions/)
- [Fantasy Worldbuilding](http://www.web-writer.net/fantasy/)
- [Setting the Fantastic in the Everyday World](https://www.writing-world.com/sf/contemporary.shtml)

**The Last Step**

- [How to know when I'm done?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/good-enough-how-to-know-when-you-re-done-7df1a16fedac)

**Celestial Mechanics**

- [Creating a realistic world(s) map - Stars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23040/creating-a-realistic-worlds-map-stars?lq=1)
- [Creating a realistic world(s) map - planetary systems](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/creating-a-realistic-worlds-map-solar-systems?lq=1)
- [Building the ultimate solar system](https://planetplanet.net/the-ultimate-solar-system/)
- [Sol Station Local Star Charts](http://www.solstation.com/#sthash.JG9BtjcG.dpbs)
- [3D Star Maps (Project Rho)](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/starmaps/index.php)
- [Orbit height and speed calculator](https://www.satsig.net/orbit-research/orbit-height-and-speed.htm)
- [Orbital Velocity Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/orbital-velocity) - allows you to easily calculate most of a planet's orbital characteristics, including eccentricity, semi-major and semi-minor axes, velocity at periapsis and apoapsis, orbital period etc. Input the information that you know or want and the calculator figures out the rest.

**Religion & Philosophy**

- [Creating a realistic world - Spreading religions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25478/creating-a-realistic-world-spreading-religions)
- [Fantasy Religion Design Guide](http://inkwellideas.com/worldbuilding/worldbuilding-religion-design/)
- [Fantasy Religion Questionnaire](https://www.deviantart.com/themusessong/art/Fantasy-Religion-Questionaire-353760571)
- Roll for Fantasy - Religion Creation - [Part 1](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/religion-creation.php), [Part 2](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/religion-creation-part-two.php), [Part 3](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/religion-creation-part-three.php)
- [A Collection of Mythology Building Resources](https://referenceforwriters.tumblr.com/post/53049866924/masterlist-original-gods-and-goddesses)
- [Creating Religions and Belief Systems](https://mythcreants.com/blog/creating-religions-belief-systems/)
- [Creating Fictional Holidays](http://fmwriters.com/Visionback/issue6/Creatingfictional.htm)
- [Mythic Scribes Worldbuilding Resources](https://mythicscribes.com/category/world-building/)
- [Internet Sacred Text Archive](https://www.sacred-texts.com/)
- [Encyclopedia Mythica](https://pantheon.org/)

**Mapping**

- [Creating a realistic world map - Landmass formation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/581/creating-a-realistic-world-map-landmass-formation)
- [Creating a realistic world map - Erosion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/creating-a-realistic-world-map-erosion?lq=1)
- [Creating a realistic world map - Coastlines](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21349/creating-a-realistic-world-map-coastlines?lq=1)
- [Creating a realistic world map - Waterways](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21402/creating-a-realistic-world-map-waterways?lq=1)
- [Creating a realistic world map - Underwater geography](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23097/creating-a-realistic-world-map-underwater-geography)
- [What tool can I use to draw a simple map of a fictional world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8896/what-tool-can-i-use-to-draw-a-simple-map-of-a-fictional-world)
- [Anyone know of a good software for making a galaxy map?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/125641/40609)
- [GoCAD](http://www.geo.tu-freiberg.de/%7Eapelm/gocad.htm) 3D Geomodeling
- [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) Open-source geographic information system
- [Build Your Own Earth](http://www.buildyourownearth.com/)
- [Map Maker 4](https://www.mapmaker.com/)
- [Azgaar's Fantasy Map Generator](https://azgaar.github.io/Fantasy-Map-Generator/) ([older version here](http://bl.ocks.org/Azgaar/b845ce22ea68090d43a4ecfb914f51bd))
- [Planet Maker](http://planetmaker.wthr.us/#)
- [Celestia](https://celestia.space/index.html)
- [Space Engine](http://spaceengine.org/)
- Texture: [CrazyBump](https://www.crazybump.com/)
- Texture: [ShaderMap](https://shadermap.com/home/)
- DonJon's [System Generator](https://donjon.bin.sh/scifi/system/)
- DonJon's [World Map Generator](https://donjon.bin.sh/scifi/world/)
- DonJon's [Fantasy Map Generator](https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/world/)
- [Planet Map Generator](https://topps.diku.dk/torbenm/maps.msp)
- [Cartography, Maps, Star Charts, and Writing](https://thewritingbug.tumblr.com/post/30846898623/cartography-maps-star-charts-and-writing)
- [Decorative Map Making](http://www.decorative-maps.com/)
- Martin O'Leary - [Generating fantasy maps](http://mewo2.com/notes/terrain/)
- [Earth Political Border Map Maker](https://yulin-w.github.io/alternate-history-editor/main.html)
- NBOS Software's [Astrosynthesis Star Mapping Sofware](https://www.nbos.com/products/astrosynthesis/) AstroSynthesis can map out large portions of space - plotting stars, interstellar routes, and sub-sectors. Zoom in and out of your sector, pan and rotate around stars, follow routes, complete with animation effects - all in 3D space. The built-in generator can also generate detailed solar system information for each star system: planets , their moons, asteroid belts, and other types of bodies. Generate extended planetary data - atmospheres, surface gravity, temperature, and more. The NBOS site claims that it applies scientific principles during generation, taking into consideration matters of astronomy, physics, atmospheric chemistry, and planetary sciences during the generation process.

**Climate & Weather**

- [Worldbuilding & Climate: How does the sun affect a simple sphere with atmosphere?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/103694/40609)
- [Creating a realistic world map - Currents, Precipitation and Climate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1353)
- [Creating a realistic world - Thermohaline circulation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25721)
- [Universe Sandbox<sup>2</sup>](https://store.steampowered.com/app/230290/Universe_Sandbox/) This highly versatile program could be listed in a number of places on this list. It's here due to its frequent use to simulate weather patterns. But don't let that stop you from using it to simulate your solar system....
- [EdGCM](http://edgcm.columbia.edu/) Geoclimate model
- [PCMDI](https://pcmdi.llnl.gov/?cmip5/) Program for Climate Model Diagnosis & Intercomparison (was CMIP5)
- [Build Your Own Earth](http://www.buildyourownearth.com/)
- [Monash Simple Climate Model](http://monash.edu/research/simple-climate-model/mscm/index.html)
- [Open Climate Workbench](https://climate.apache.org/)
- [ClimaSim](http://www.weathergraphics.com/climasim/)
- [WxSim](https://www.wxsim.com/index.htm)
- [Weather and Worldbuilding 101](http://fmwriters.com/Visionback/issue6/weatherandworld.htm)
- [Planet Map Generator](https://topps.diku.dk/torbenm/maps.msp) – biome overlay
- [EcoNet 2.2](http://eco.engr.uga.edu/index.html) Climate/ecosystem modelling online tool, Earth-like.
- [Earth Flood Map](https://www.floodmap.net/) flooding map with actual Earth satellite imagery. It's worth noting that if all the ice caps melted, it's estimated the oceans would rise approximately [230 feet](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-would-sea-level-change-if-all-glaciers-melted).
- [Mean Temperature Calculator](https://web.archive.org/web/20220519173816/https://www.astro.indiana.edu/ala/PlanetTemp/index.html) Calculates mean planetary temperature given star mass, orbital radius, albedo and greenhouse gases as a ratio of Earth's values.
- [Monash Simple Climate Simulator](https://sci-web46-v01.ocio.monash.edu/mscm/greb/cgi-bin/scny_i18n.py) showing the changes in temperature of various aspects of the Earth over time based on various affects.

**Geography**

- [Creating a realistic world map - Mineralogy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25084/creating-a-realistic-world-map-mineralogy)
- [Creating a realistic world map - Fuel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/creating-a-realistic-world-map-fuel)
- [How do I create realistic geography?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/19815/40609)
- [Earth Impacts Effects Program](https://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEarth/ImpactEffects/) estimates the effects of an item impacting the earth.
- [The Fundamentals of Physical Geography](http://www.physicalgeography.net/fundamentals/contents.html)
- [Standford Roman Travel and Route Calculator](https://orbis.stanford.edu/)
- [How to Create Sensible Plate Tectonics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/247575/40609)

**Flora & Fauna**

- [Creating a realistic world map - Vegetation/Biomes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23941/creating-a-realistic-world-map-vegetation-biomes)
  [Creating a realistic world map - Fuel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/creating-a-realistic-world-map-fuel)

**History & Culture**

- [RFF - History Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/history-creation.php)
- [Music for Your Fantasy World](http://fmwriters.com/Visionback/Issue%2012/Themeartsin.htm)
- [Historically Authentic Sexism in Fantasy](https://www.tor.com/2012/12/06/historically-authentic-sexism-in-fantasy-lets-unpack-that/)
- [Everyday Life in the Middle Ages](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zm4mn39/revision/2)
- [Donjon Fantasy Calendar Generator:](https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/calendar/) Free Calendar generator that allows you to change the number of days in a year/week/month, allows you to edit phases of the moon and lets you add Notes and Holidays.

**Magic**

- Brandon Sanderson’s Three Laws of Magic - [First Law](https://brandonsanderson.com/sandersons-first-law/), [Second Law](https://brandonsanderson.com/sandersons-second-law/), [Third Law](https://brandonsanderson.com/sandersons-third-law-of-magic/)
- [World Building: Magic Systems](https://www.erindorpress.com/2013/11/world-building-magic-systems/)
- [My Magic System Checklist](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/comments/59qamy/my_magic_system_checklist/)
- [RFF - Magic Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/magic-creation.php)
- [RFF - Superpower Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/superpower-creation.php)
- [Defining the Sources, Costs, and Effects of Magic](https://www.writing-world.com/sf/magic.shtml)
- [12 Questions to Ask Yourself About Your Magic System](http://www.intergalacticmedicineshow.com/cgi-bin/mag.cgi?do=columns&vol=mette_ivie_harrison&article=079)
- [How to Create a Rational Magic System](https://mythcreants.com/blog/how-to-create-a-rational-magic-system/)

**Creature Design**

- The [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/40609) of Creature Building Questions.
- [RFF - Animal Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/animal-creation.php)
- [RFF - Character Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/character-creation.php)
- [RFF - Species Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/species-creation.php)
- [Dragons and other large winged creatures](http://markwitton-com.blogspot.com/2018/05/why-we-think-giant-pterosaurs-could-fly.html)

**Military, Weapons and Apparel**

- [RFF - Armour and Weapon Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/armor-weapon-creation.php)
- [RFF - Army Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/army-creation.php)
- [RFF - Clothing Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/clothing-creation.php)
- Roll for Fantasy - Warrior Guide - [African](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/warrior-guide-african.php), [American](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/warrior-guide-americas.php), [East Asian](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/warrior-guide-east-asian.php), [Indian](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/warrior-guide-indian.php)
- [The Effects of Nuclear Weapons](https://www.deepspace.ucsb.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Effects-of-Nuclear-Weapons-1977-3rd-edition-complete.pdf) (1977). Please do not ask a question about nuclear effects until you've reviewed this document.

**Cities and Societies**

- [Creating a realistic world - Spreading languages](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25396/creating-a-realistic-world-spreading-languages)
- [Creating a realistic world map - Countries Borders](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23820/creating-a-realistic-world-map-countries-borders?rq=1)
- [Creating a realistic world - Governments](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25524/creating-a-realistic-world-governements)
- [RFF - Building Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/building-creation.php)
- [RFF - City Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/city-creation.php)
- [RFF - Society Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/society-creation.php)
- [RFF - Name Styles](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/name-styles.php)
- [S. John Ross - Medieval Demographics Made Easy](https://web.archive.org/web/20180925185100/http://www222.pair.com/sjohn/blueroom/demog.htm)
- [Software] [Medieval Fantasy City Generator](https://watabou.itch.io/medieval-fantasy-city-generator)
- [International Standard Classification of Occupations (ISCO-08)](https://www.ilo.org/wcmsp5/groups/public/---dgreports/---dcomm/---publ/documents/publication/wcms_172572.pdf)

**Economics**

- [Creating a realistic world - Governments](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25524/creating-a-realistic-world-governements)
- [Money Matters for the Intrepid Traveller](https://cbbforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=6144&p=256399&hilit=money%20matters#p256399)
- [List of price of medieval items](http://medieval.ucdavis.edu/120D/Money.html)
- [donjon Medieval Demographics Calculator](https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/demographics/)
- [The Domesday Book](https://www.rpglibrary.org/utils/meddemog/) on the web

**Food & Farming**

- [Creately food web designer](https://creately.com/lp/food-web-maker/)

- [Insight Maker](https://insightmaker.com/tag/food-web)
- [Visual Paradigm](https://online.visual-paradigm.com/diagrams/templates/interrelationship-diagram/food-chain-interrelationship-diagram/)

**Simulators and/or Games**

*This section is not for calculators. Please put calculators under the topical heading most appropriate above.*

- [Solar System Simulator](https://simpop.org/solar-system/solar-system.htm) - A simple Sol system simulator demonstrating orbit speeds by distance and mass. Allows you to place known planetary bodies anywhere you want.
- [Solar System Scope](https://www.solarsystemscope.com/) - Simulates the Sol system in remarkable detail, but does not allow modifications to the system.
- [Solar System Simulator](http://www.scigames.org/game.php?id=planetfamilies2) - One of the most fun, it simulates both the orbits and the gravitational effects. You can make multi-sun systems and try to create stable planetary orbits. Colliding suns make bigger suns. Limitations make it cumbersome to create specific systems, but a lot of fun.
- Questions asked using the [software-recommendations](/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) tag may have other options not included in this list.

**Science and Technology**

- [RFF - Fictional Technology Creation](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/fictional-technology.php)
- [A Slower Speed of Light](http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/). This game, developed by MIT, helps world builders understand the effects of special relativity and how things are "seen" as one approaches the speed of light (or, in the case of the game, by "slowing light down to walking speed.")
- [Atomic Rockets](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/prelimnotes.php)
- [Medieval Technology](http://fmwriters.com/Visionback/Issue%2011/advcuttechnolog.htm)
- [1989 Rockwell International Integrated Space Plan](https://cdn.makezine.com/uploads/2013/07/integratedspaceplan2color.pdf)
- [Lexicon of Locks and Keys](https://www.historicallocks.com/en/site/h/historicallocks/dictionary/)

**Science Calculators**

- [Conservation of Momentum (Collisions)](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/conservation-of-momentum)
- [Car Crash Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/car-crash-force)
- [Physics inside a Rotating Space Colony Calculator](https://jsfiddle.net/nosajimiki/k98z2h1a/240/)

**Language**

- [Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory): [The importance of language in world building](https://medium.com/universe-factory/a-disease-of-mythology-the-importance-of-language-in-worldbuilding-d1a9d1f1e2f4)
- Roll for Fantasy - Language Creation - [Part 1](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/language-creation.php), [Part 2](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/language-creation-part-two.php), [Part 3](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/language-creation-part-three.php), [Part 4](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/language-creation-part-four.php), [Part 5](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/language-creation-part-five.php)
- Roll for Fantasy - Body Language - [Part 1](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/writing-body-language.php), [Part 2](https://rollforfantasy.com/guides/writing-body-language-part-two.php)
- [Constructed Languages Stack](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/)
- [The Language Construction Kit](http://www.zompist.com/kit.html)
- [The International Phonetic Alphabet](http://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm)

**Youtube Channels and Podcasts about Worldbuilding**

- [Hello Future Me](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFQMO-YL87u-6Rt8hIVsRjA)
- [Web DM](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7XFmdssWgaPzGyGbKk8GaQ)
- [Shadiversity](https://www.youtube.com/user/shadmbrooks)
- [How to be a Great Game Master](https://m.youtube.com/user/Bon3zmann/featured)
- [World Anvil Worldbuilding](https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCf5MDxxTuT1OpwOxVfG-ofg)
- [Writing Excuses on World Building](https://writingexcuses.com/tag/worldbuilding/)
- [Artifexian](https://www.youtube.com/user/Artifexian)
- [Biblaridion](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMjTcpv56G_W0FRIdPHBn4A)
- [University course on writing by Brandon Sanderson; Episode 4 is about Worldbuilding and Episode 8 about Magic systems](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLH3mK1NZn9QqOSj3ObrP3xL8tEJQ12-vL)
- [Science & Futurism with Isaac Arthur](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZFipeZtQM5CKUjx6grh54g)
- [Phrenotopia's Alien Evolution Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kbIoEx7mmc&list=PLbAr0DK7A_W5Fx4qJhXFnNeMbhox15tdi)

**Worldbuilding Discussion Forums**

[We've been asked](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132660/worldbuilding-forum-or-other-conversational-place) about places to go for discussion beyond mere Q&A. There are several excellent long form discussion forums focusing on worldbuilding.

- [**CBB**](https://cbbforum.com) -- a discussion forum catering to invented languages & worlds
- [**Reddit Worldbuilding**](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/) -- general worldbuilding forum
- [**Reddit Fantasy Worldbuilding**](https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyWorldbuilding/) -- a narrow focus
- [**Reddit Fantasy Maps**](https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyMaps/) -- fantasy cartography
- [**Reddit Fantasy Writers**](https://www.reddit.com/r/fantasywriters/) -- for writers
- [**GTX0**](http://gtx0.com) -- Currently dead, but known to revive from time to time
- [**ZBB**](http://www.verduria.org/) -- another general purpose invented language & culture forum
- Worldbuilding's own [**Factory Floor**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) -- you love our answers, join the discussion!

Those are the main ones, and there are certainly other highly specialised forums as well.

**World-Building Software**

*Software in this category is designed to help manage the process of worldbuilding rather than specific aspects of worldbuilding (e.g., climate simulation, mapping), which may be dealt with in greater detail with dedicated tools.*

- [FrathWiki](http://www.frathwiki.com/Main_Page): a great place to store the articles you've written about your invented worlds, cultures, languages and histories; easy to use Media Wiki style, no unnecessary bells and whistles
- [World Anvil:](https://worldanvil.com) Free tool (you can pay to remove ads).  Allows you to consolidate your world building contents online.  Covers timelines, geography, religion, allows for uploading and pinning maps, and a whole bunch of other stuff.
- [Scabard:](https://www.scabard.com/pbs/page/main/About) Free with a private mode available for $40 yearly subscription. This is geared (heavily) towards RPG & TableTop campaigns but has many tools for general Worldbuilding. Offers: Map creation, Timelines, Event handling, Character/Group/Item/Location creation options, and graph options for mapping connections.
- [ChronoGrapher](https://chronographer.net/info): a wiki-style notetaking and worldbuilding tool with support for deep time and history tracking. Features includes: interactive and interconnected maps, an infinite tilegrid editor, custom calendars and timelines, dynamic and automatic wiki articles, completely private projects and ability to collaborate.

**Books**

*There are a very large number of books about or contributing to worldbuilding.  This is not the place to list them all.  It is the place to list those that have been mentioned in questions and answers posted on this site.  Please list the book (with link to Amazon or the author's website), the author's name, and links to the WB.SE posts that cite the book.*

- [Architect of Worlds](https://www.adastragames.com): Jon Zeigler; mentioned [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/254033/im-a-publisher-with-a-book-that-might-be-of-use-to-this-stackexchange) (now deleted). A " Layman's explanation of astronomy and planetary sciences with random tables and worked through examples."
- [World-Building](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014V4EDAI): Stephen L. Gillett; mentioned in  [1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/139147/40609), [2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/120616/40609) (originally part of the [Science Fiction Writing Series](https://www.librarything.com/series/Science+Fiction+Writing+Series))
- [On Writing and Worldbuilding](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=on+writing+and+worldbuilding): Volume One;  Timothy Hickson; mentioned in [1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/148558/62187)
- [Xenology: An Introduction to the Scientific Study of Extraterrestrial Life, Intelligence, and Civilization](http://www.xenology.info/Xeno.htm);  Robert A. Freitas Jr.; mentioned in [1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/253033/40609). Note that the contents of this book are available free online.